# Reducing the number of requests to web service

Tags: c#, web-services, client, asmx, server

I have a C# web service (.net 3.5 .asmx).

I want to send a data from web service to client without send a request from the client .

***example:***

if I have a web service chat, and there are two client connected to it (`user1`, `user2`) , `user1` sends a message to `user2`, how I can send this message to `user2` without a request from `user2` to the web service to get new messages

Comment: Perhaps you should look at [SignalR](http://signalr.net/)

Comment: This task not for webservice. Look at web sockets (SignalR or socket.io)

Comment: If you are creating a chat system why re-invent the wheel just look at ejabberd or other XMPP chat clients. They have addressed this.  I agree with all the comment do not use web services for this it is not a good fit.

Answer (score 0):

Through the use of [websockets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/WebSockets), you can have a persistent connection between the server and clients which allows clients to receive messages without having to poll the server. [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/) is a "real-time engine" that abstracts away many of the lower level details of implementing websockets. [Here](https://github.com/Quobject/SocketIoClientDotNet) is a library that may be of use to you in implementing it on a C# web server.